# Is "Anonymous" based on a true story?

Tags: historical-accuracy, anonymous

I watched *Anonymous* (2011). The movie shows that Shakespeare was fraud and all his writing originally belongs to some nobleman.

Is it true? If yes, then what is the source of the story and what is the evidence in favour? If it is not true, how was anyone allowed to make this kind movie, spreading fake information? This is seems to be a serious case of diminishing the legacy of such a great writer without any solid proof.

Comment: Why do you think someone would not be allowed to make a movie with fake information?

Comment: @jeffronicus Defamation is a crime,if anybody do not have enough evidence in favour of allegation.In my country it comes under criminal law, not civil. I think it's right .No one should have the right to pose allegations on anyone ,dead or alive, without solid evidences,

Comment: Can a dead person be the passive of defamation? Can a clearly-marked fiction defame someone?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxfordian_theory_of_Shakespeare_authorship

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The movie's plot is a conflation of several 'conspiracy theories' which have surrounded Shakespeare for many years.

It's far far too complex to even attempt to précis here, so I shall suffice with the opening paragraph from [Wikipedia - Shakespeare authorship question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakespeare_authorship_question) - please read it all to have any grasp of how complex it is.

> The Shakespeare authorship question is the argument that someone other
>   than William Shakespeare of Stratford-upon-Avon wrote the works
>   attributed to him. Anti-Stratfordians—a collective term for adherents
>   of the various alternative-authorship theories—believe that
>   Shakespeare of Stratford was a front to shield the identity of the
>   real author or authors, who for some reason did not want or could not
>   accept public credit. Although the idea has attracted much public
>   interest, all but a few Shakespeare scholars and literary historians
>   consider it a fringe belief, and for the most part acknowledge it only
>   to rebut or disparage the claims